# Expanding menu/sub menu

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a menu with this HTML.

```
<div class="sidemenu-maincat">
    <img src="folder/maincat1.jpg" alt="Main cat1" id="toggle" />
</div>

<div class="sidemenu-subcat">
    <a href="submenu11.html"> - Submenu 11 </a>
</div>
<div class="sidemenu-subcat">
    <a href="submenu12.html"> - Submenu 12 </a>
</div>
<div class="sidemenu-subcat">
    <a href="submenu13.html"> - Submenu 13 </a>
</div>     

<div class="sidemenu-maincat">
    <img src="folder/main-cat2.jpg" alt="Main cat2 /> 
</div>

<div class="sidemenu-subcat">
    <a href="submenu21.html"> > Submenu 21 </a>
</div>
<div class="sidemenu-subcat">
    <a href="submenu22.html"> > Submenu 22 </a>
</div>
<div class="sidemenu-subcat">
    <a href="submenu23.html"> > Submenu 23 </a>
</div>
```

I have the "sidemenu-subcat" div hidden and I would like it to show/hide when I press the pictures on in the "sidemenu-maincat" divs. I have tried to do this with Javascript but I can't figure out how at all. I would like it not to be done with any library.

I'm keeping all my Javascripts in another document and this is the closest I've come to solve my problem:

```
function toggling()
{
    if(document.getElementByClassName("hidden").style.display == "none")
    {
        document.getElementByClassName("hidden") = "block";    
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementByClassName("hidden") = "none"; 
    }
}

function init()
{
    var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
    toggle.onclick = toggling;
}
```

I know it's far from what that needs to be done but it's the closest I've got..

Comment: Have you considered using a Javascript library like jQuery?  It makes manipulating the DOM considerably easier.

Comment: @TheronLuhn For whatever reason the OP wants to do this without a library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I do prefer to use a library for this type of thing but I put together a pure javascript example for you.  Though there is probably a better way to do it.

Firstly, each submenu should be contained within the it's maincat div and given a hidden class so it is hidden on page load.

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ojedaf/2/edit)

```
.sidemenu-subcat.hidden {
    display: none;  
}

var sideMenuOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-maincat');
for (var i = 0; i < sideMenuOptions.length; i++) {
  sideMenuOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var subMenuItems = this.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-subcat');
    for (var s = 0; s < subMenuItems.length; s++) {
      var subItem = subMenuItems[s];
      // if the element is not visible it's offsets will be 0
      if (subItem.offsetWidth === 0 && subItem.offsetHeight === 0) {
        subItem.className = 'sidemenu-subcat';
      } else {
        subItem.className = subItem.className + ' hidden';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I see that the example works fine but I can't figure out how to get this to work for me when I'm using an external JS document. I have tried <script type="text/javascript" src"myjs.js"> </script> but it doesn't do anything. Do you mind helping me solving this issue? And I already had the .sidemnu-subcat { display:none; } in my css since before.

Comment: It's probably because your script is running before the document has finished loading. Wrap your code in a initialize function and call it when the body has loaded.  Change the body tag to `<body onload="initialize()">`.. Or just place your script tag at the bottom of your html page just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Also note that the CSS for `.sidemenu-subcat` should not have display as hidden.  I created a subclass `.sidemenu-subcat.hidden`. @Benji

Comment: So I should keep my .sidemenu-subcat not hidden, and also create .sidemenu-subcat.hidden { display:none; } ?

Comment: @Benji Well that's how I set my example up.  Each submenu item has the hidden class already applied in the html so it is hidden when the page loads. And the javascript then removes that hidden class on the click event and since the `.sidemenu-subcat` is not hidden, the menu items appear.

Comment: "SeainMalkin Alright, just wanted to make sure. Thanks again!

Comment: @Benji Thats the fun of not using a library, you need to cater for all the browser specific implementations.  If you need further help with specific things, create a new question.